# Removing spaces from the fields in a semicolon-delimited file using shell script

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
03139; 5;        IT1234978208; 20150930  ;  CTZ 13/31.12.15;
03137; 6;        IT1234978206; 20151015  ;  CTZ 13/31.11.18;
....
....
03134; 8;        IT1234974406; 20151212  ;  CTZ 13/37.13.17;
```

I'm searching for a workaround to remove all whitespaces for every csv lines by use `sed` command on Korn Shell for got something like this:

```
03139;5;IT1234978208;20150930;CTZ 13/31.12.15;
03137;6;IT1234978206;20151015;CTZ 13/31.11.18;
....
....
03134;8;IT1234974406;20151212;CTZ 13/37.13.17;
```

Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: Looks like you want almost every space removed. Maybe just the ones immediately surrounding a semicolon?

Comment: If you're not stuck on using `sed`, another option might be to use `awk` and set `FS="[ \t]*;[ \t]*"; OFS=";"`

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you want to remove only those spaces that are before or after a semicolon.  In that case:

```
$ sed 's/[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*/;/g' text
03139;5;IT1234978208;20150930;CTZ 13/31.12.15;
03137;6;IT1234978206;20151015;CTZ 13/31.11.18;
....
....
03134;8;IT1234974406;20151212;CTZ 13/37.13.17;
```

#### How it works:

The sed substitution command typically looks like `s/old/new/` where `old` is a regular expression.  In this case, we add a `g` suffix to indicate *global* substitution (as opposed to just substituting one instance).  In our case, `old` matches any a `;` and any surrounding white space: `s/[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*`.  This is replaced by `new` which is just a `;`.

Comment: I think you could just combine both replacements and go with just "s/[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*/;/g;"

Comment: @ilkkachu Very good!  Answer updated with a single `s` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pick up `perl`, because then you can `split` and `join`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split /;/; 
   s/\s+//g for @fields;
   print join ";", @fields, "\n";
}

__DATA__
03139; 5;        IT1234978208; 20150930  ;  CTZ 13/31.12.15;
03137; 6;        IT1234978206; 20151015  ;  CTZ 13/31.11.18;
03134; 8;        IT1234974406; 20151212  ;  CTZ 13/37.13.17;
```

Now, that strips all spaces in the fields, giving:

```
03139;5;IT1234978208;20150930;CTZ13/31.12.15;
03137;6;IT1234978206;20151015;CTZ13/31.11.18;
03134;8;IT1234974406;20151212;CTZ13/37.13.17;
```

But if you just want to strip leading/trailing space:

s/^\s+|\s+$//g for @fields;

This can one-line-ify as:

```
perl -F; -lape 's/^\s+|\s+$//g for @F; print join ";", @F;'
```

Where:

- `-F;` sets delimiter
- `-l` says remove/re-add line endings automatically.
- `-a` is autosplit (on the delimiter in `-F` or white space by default)
- `-e` is "execute this snippet".